# Resampling pandas timeseries without computing a new offset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in timeseries data that contains only the available times.  This leads to a `Series` with no missing values, but an unequally spaced index.  I'd like to convert this to a `Series` with an equally spaced index with missing values.  Since I don't know a priori what the spacing will be, I'm currently using a function like

```
min_dt      = np.diff(series.index.values).min()
new_spacing = pandas.DateOffset(days=min_dt.days, seconds=min_dt.seconds,
                                microseconds=min_dt.microseconds)
series      = series.asfreq(new_spacing)
```

to compute what the spacing should be (note that this is using Pandas 0.7.3 - the 0.8 beta code looks slightly differently since I have to use series.index.to_pydatetime() for correct behavior with Numpy 1.6).

Is there an easier way to do this operation using the pandas library?

Answer (score 0):

If you want NaN's in the places where there is no data, you can just use `Minute()` located in datetools (as of pandas 0.7.x)

```
from pandas.core.datetools import day, Minute
tseries.asfreq(Minute())
```

That should provide an evenly spaced time series with 1 minute differences with NaNs as the series values where there is no data.

Comment: As you say, this would lead to a one-minute spacing between entries.  I'm trying to get it where they're evenly spaced where the spacing is equal to the minimum spacing I have between entries (i.e. what the "actual" frequency of the data is - every 24 hours or every 12 hours, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. In that case I'm not sure if there is an easier way than what you've got. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, nothing's "wrong", but as I learn more of the pandas library I'd like to avoid re-implementing builtin functions that I don't know about.  Also, having to use the explicit values of the index with NumPy caused some issues in pandas 0.8.0 beta that uses the NumPy datetime type where the datetimes looked fine from the pandas index, but looking at the underlying NumPy array gave strange values and an incorrect computation.